# Mill Game in Xamarin XAML c# win8

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, windows-8

I want to make a Mill Game in Xamarin. I want buttons in specific locations in grid. These locations are coming from my ViewModel like this, but i dont know how to do it after browsing forums.

I want empty spaces or lines between buttons

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:Malom.Portable.View"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:DLToolkit.Forms.Controls;assembly=DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView"
             x:Class="Malom.Portable.View.GamePage">

   <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <Style x:Key="EllipseStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding Color}" Value="BluePlayer">
                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Blue" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding Color}" Value="RedPlayer">
                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding Color}" Value="Empty">
                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Black" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}" HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                            <Grid Padding="30,30,30,30" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                              <Button Grid.Row="{Binding Y}" Grid.Column="{Binding X}" Command="{Binding FieldChangeCommand}"></Button>
                            </Grid>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: if you want your buttons at specific locations in the grid, do no place them inside of a ListView.  Programatically place them directly into the Grid.

Comment: How can i give an itemsource to my Grid? Or should i use another item container? I want my buttons in specific locations like in the game

Comment: you can't databind to a grid - that's why I said you have to assign the buttons programatically

Comment: I see. Is there any other method for putting Buttons or anything on screen in specific locations with databind? I cant find any... thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate through your list of Fields and programatically create a button and assign it to your Grid:

```
foreach(var field in Fields)
{
  myGrid.Children.Add(new Button { Text = field.Name }, field.X, field.Y);
}
```

Comment: im only allowed to use XAML i can't use any behind codes for the view... but thank you. I have to do it in MVVM architecture. And i can't use any code in ViewModel that create stuff on view like add new buttons

Comment: @szarkabarna you haven't understood MVVM then.